# Usage of "being" in "I am always afraid of being bitten"

Tags: grammar, gerunds, passive-voice

Does anybody know what 'being' means in the following statement?

> I don't like dogs. I am always afraid of being bitten.

Why is *being* used in this statement? It looks like a passive statement, but if it is, it shouldn't start with the subject, but rather be *object + verb + past participle*. But here it starts with the subject *I*. Please advise.

Answer (score 8):

*Afraid of* takes a noun phrase, such as

> I am always afraid of snakes

which is often a non-finite clause with a verb in the gerund (*-ing* form)

> I am always afraid of falling
>
> I am always afraid of looking stupid
>
> I am always afraid of walking alone at night.

Here the clause contains a passive verb, so the gerund is formed with the gerund of the auxiliary *be*:

> I am always afraid of being bitten

The main clause is active: *I am always afraid of X*. It is only the embedded non-finite clause which is passive.

Comment: Interestingly, "afraid" was 'originally past participle of afray "frighten"', according to the online etymological dictionary,  so it was likely a passive originally.  Perhaps some diachronic linguist and nincompoop might even suppose it to continue its existence as a defective verb in contemporary English...